# How to convert Facet Data to Json format

Tags: xdb, experience-profile, custom-field, json

I am working on display facet data on the Experience profile tab. I am following the below article for the same.

http://zhenyuan.azurewebsites.net/post/displaying-custom-facets-in-contact-profile

But when I am hitting my custom tab, debugger comes to defined routes (Controller and Action) which I registered and successfully returns the Custom Facts data, but unfortunately, it's throwing me below different error's on the console:

> (1) ExceptionMessage: "The 'ObjectContent'1' type failed to serialize the
>
> response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'."
>
> (2) Exception Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected with type 'Sitecore.XConnect.Schema.XdbProperty'. Path 'XObject[0].Key.DeclaringType.DeclaredProperties'.

**URL** which executes on custom tab click is:

`http://helixbase.sc/sitecore/api/ao/v1/contacts/a2c0c034-c6f9-0000-0000-058b1d973da1/customformfields/`

If I execute this URL in the seperate tab then it returns me value as below:

> {"k__BackingField":"Prince Sharma","k__BackingField":"Prince.Sharma@gmail.com","k__BackingField":"9654477778","k__BackingField":"Sharma","k__BackingField":"PAS34567NUM890","k__BackingField":"Hindi","k__BackingField":"10b430b2-a9c1-463b-be1e-315af66fdbde","k__BackingField":"2019-04-25T11:05:16.7443003Z","k__BackingField":true}

**JS File**

```
define(["sitecore", "/-/speak/v1/experienceprofile/DataProviderHelper.js",
"/-/speak/v1/experienceprofile/CintelUtl.js"],
function (sc, providerHelper, cintelUtil) {
    var app = sc.Definitions.App.extend({
        initialized: function () {
            var localUrl = "/customformfields/";
            providerHelper.setupHeaders([
                { urlKey: localUrl }
            ]);
            //providerHelper.addDefaultTransformerKey();
            var url = sc.Contact.baseUrl + localUrl;
            var $that = this;
            providerHelper.initProvider(this.customDataProvider, "", url, this.customTabMessageBar);
            providerHelper.getData(this.customDataProvider,
                $.proxy(function (jsondata) {
                    cintelUtil.setText($that.SurNameValue, jsondata.SurName, true);
                    cintelUtil.setText($that.PassportValue, jsondata.PassportNumber, true);
                }));
        }
    });
    return app;
});
```

Rest of the `Controller, Action, InitializeRoutes code` I implemented the same as an above-defined article. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have faced the same issue during the implementation of Display custom facet on the Experience profile tab. @x3mxray helped me as well to implement the same.

As per the article 
http://zhenyuan.azurewebsites.net/post/displaying-custom-facets-in-contact-profile
you followed, the controller will return your facets values, but it's not serialized so you will get this type of error.

I have serialized Facets Values using `Newtonsoft.Json` and after that, it works fine for me. Here `Newtonsoft.Json` will serialize and give you a string object so before return, it to the JSON data you need to parse it as below: (taken code sample from your refered article)

```
try
{
    var contactManager = GetContactManager();
    var contact = contactManager.LoadContactReadOnly(contactId);
    if (contact == null)
    {
        throw new ContactNotFoundException();
    }
    var subscriptionsFacet = contact.GetFacet<ISubscriptions>("Subscriptions");
    var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ContractResolver = new XdbJsonContractResolver(client.Model, serializeFacets: true, serializeContactInteractions: true),
        DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc,
        DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore
    };
    return Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(subscriptionsFacet, serializerSettings));
}
catch (ContactNotFoundException ex)
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex.Message);
}
```

You can find serialization setting more details from [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/serialize-xconnect-entities-using-json-net.html).

Comment: Thanks for the support. It works fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is that each facet has an `XObject` object on it that contains a lot of circular references. The XObject will never serialize, you just need to tell NewtonSoft to ignore it when serializing. You can do this with a DefaultContractResolver.

You can see this working in my repo. https://github.com/buildabonfire/Bonfire.Analytics.Dto
Your facets will look like this:

```
{
   "Key": "Emails",
      "Value": {
      "Others": {},
      "PreferredKey": "Primary Email",
      "PreferredEmail": {
      "Validated": false,
      "SmtpAddress": "myemail@gmail.com",
      "BounceCount": 0
   },
   "ConcurrencyToken": "9685b921-6c5a-4cde-becd-74e9b3f6d74c",
   "LastModified": "2019-05-14T02:31:56.2523352Z",
   "ClrTypePresent": true
   }
},
{
   "Key": "Personal",
   "Value": {
      "Birthdate": "1971-10-12T00:00:00Z",
      "FirstName": "Chris",
      "MiddleName": null,
      "LastName": "Auer",
      "Gender": "M",
      "JobTitle": null,
      "Nickname": null,
      "Suffix": null,
      "Title": null,
      "PreferredLanguage": null,
      "ConcurrencyToken": "e73f4cad-0264-4a8d-bba4-c51b1293b6d8",
      "LastModified": "2019-04-28T16:30:43.7406558Z",
      "ClrTypePresent": true
   }
},
```

I have a custom controller action that returns Json Text.
https://github.com/buildabonfire/Bonfire.Analytics.Dto/blob/master/Bonfire.Analytics.Dto/Serialization/JsonNet.cs

### PropertyRenameAndIgnoreSerializerContractResolver

This is the code that will tell NewtonSoft to ignore a property.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

namespace Bonfire.Analytics.Dto.Extensions
{
    public class PropertyRenameAndIgnoreSerializerContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<Type, HashSet<string>> _ignores;
        private readonly Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, string>> _renames;

        public PropertyRenameAndIgnoreSerializerContractResolver()
        {
            _ignores = new Dictionary<Type, HashSet<string>>();
            _renames = new Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, string>>();
        }

        public void IgnoreProperty(Type type, params string[] jsonPropertyNames)
        {
            if (!_ignores.ContainsKey(type))
                _ignores[type] = new HashSet<string>();

            foreach (var prop in jsonPropertyNames)
                _ignores[type].Add(prop);
        }

        public void RenameProperty(Type type, string propertyName, string newJsonPropertyName)
        {
            if (!_renames.ContainsKey(type))
                _renames[type] = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            _renames[type][propertyName] = newJsonPropertyName;
        }

        protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
        {
            var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

            if (IsIgnored(property.DeclaringType, property.PropertyName))
            {
                property.ShouldSerialize = i => false;
                property.Ignored = true;
            }

            if (IsRenamed(property.DeclaringType, property.PropertyName, out var newJsonPropertyName))
                property.PropertyName = newJsonPropertyName;

            return property;
        }

        private bool IsIgnored(Type type, string jsonPropertyName)
        {
            if (!_ignores.ContainsKey(type))
                return false;

            return _ignores[type].Contains(jsonPropertyName);
        }

        private bool IsRenamed(Type type, string jsonPropertyName, out string newJsonPropertyName)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> renames;

            if (!_renames.TryGetValue(type, out renames) || !renames.TryGetValue(jsonPropertyName, out newJsonPropertyName))
            {
                newJsonPropertyName = null;
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

### Executing the serialization

```
{
    var jsonResolver = new PropertyRenameAndIgnoreSerializerContractResolver();

    // THIS IS WHERE WE TELL IT TO IGNORE XObject
    jsonResolver.IgnoreProperty(typeof(XdbExtensible), "XObject");

    var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    serializerSettings.ContractResolver = jsonResolver;

    var formatting = Formatting.None;
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var sw = new StringWriter(sb);

    var writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw) { Formatting = formatting };
    var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(serializerSettings);
    serializer.Serialize(writer, this.Data);

    // your JSON is in sb.ToString()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you try to return Sitecore.XConnect.Facet in server response to browser. Facet is a complex model with generic self-referenced properties.

Try to create a simple class for view model only with fields that you need on client side, populate them from facet and use it for server response instead of Facet model.

I have also faced this issue when I implemented custom tab with all contact facets for Experience profile. You should skip 'native' properties of Sitecore.XConnect.Facet type for output to resolve this issue.

Example of my custom report processor:

```
 public  class PopulateWithFacetData: ReportProcessorBase
 {
        private static readonly Type BaseType = typeof(Sitecore.XConnect.Facet);
        readonly List<string> _skippedProperties = BaseType.GetProperties().Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
        private const int maxDepth = 3;
        private bool IsDefaultProperty(string propertyName)
        {
                return _skippedProperties.Contains(propertyName);
        }

        public override void Process(ReportProcessorArgs args)
        {
            var xConnectService = new XconnectService();
            var facets = Task.Run(() => xConnectService.GetContactFacets(args.ReportParameters.ContactId)).Result;

            var table = CreateDataTable(facets); 
            args.ResultSet.Data.Dataset[args.ReportParameters.ViewName] = table;
        }

        public DataTable CreateDataTable(IReadOnlyDictionary<string,Facet> list)
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

            dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FacetName", "".GetType()));
            dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FieldName", "".GetType()));
            dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FieldValue", "".GetType()));
            dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DepthLevel", "".GetType()));
            dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Type", "".GetType()));
            foreach (var entity in list)
            {
                if(entity.Key!="Avatar")
                    AddChildren(ref dataTable, entity.Key, entity.Value, 0);
            }

            return dataTable;
        }

        private void AddChildren(ref DataTable dataTable,string contactFacetName, dynamic obj, int depth, string typePath="")
        {
            if (depth > maxDepth) return; 
            Type type = obj.GetType();
            var properties = type.GetProperties();
            foreach (var p in properties)
            {
                object[] values = new object[5];

                values[0] = contactFacetName;
                values[1] = p.Name;
                var value = p.GetValue(obj) ?? "";
                values[2] = value;
                values[3] = depth;


                Type valueType = value.GetType();
                if (valueType.FullName != null)
                {
                    if (!valueType.FullName.StartsWith("System.Collections"))
                        if (!IsDefaultProperty(p.Name))
                        {
                            var path = typePath+ "$" + values[1];
                            values[4] = typePath;
                            if (valueType.Namespace.StartsWith("System"))
                            {
                                dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                values[2] = "$object$";
                                dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
                                AddChildren(ref dataTable, contactFacetName, value, depth+1, path);
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }

}
```

I used reflection to make solution generic. You can easy adapt it for your concrete facet. We implemented it for previous year Hackathon (sitecore 9.0), I hope it can be useful for your custom tab implementation. https://github.com/Sitecore-Hackathon/2018-Sitecore-Friends/blob/master/documentation/README.md

Comment: This is very because Sitecore just sends back objects at run time. The real facet can be of any type. You will have to use a lot of reflector to find the type and new up a new one. I went this route and it turned into a mess.

Comment: Yes, this is because of cycled reference in XObject field. I faced the same issue when I implemented generic model for all facets read/write operations for my custom experience profile tab. And I solved it with skipping 'native' facet properties for output model. That is what I mean. Custom output model can solve it without diving in serializer. https://github.com/Sitecore-Hackathon/2018-Sitecore-Friends/blob/master/documentation/README.md

Comment: Nice. You should post some of that code so it is available for the next person.

Comment: Thank you. I add clarification in my answer.